# NPM command showing aborted message due to not enough memory in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm

I am new in nodejs when i am using npm command, i am getting bellow errors

```
 $ npm install express --save
 Error: ENOMEM: not enough memory, scandir '/home/buraqtechno'

<--- Last few GCs --->
[32765:0x23f0eb0]      216 ms: Mark-sweep 6.3 (14.8) -> 6.3 (14.8) MB,     7.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.025, current mu = 0.025) allocation failure GC  in old space requested[32765:0x23f0eb0]      225 ms: Mark-sweep 6.3 (14.8) - > 6.2 (11.3) MB, 8.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.018, current mu = 0.011) last  resort GC in old space requested
[32765:0x23f0eb0]      232 ms: Mark-sweep 6.2 (11.3) -> 6.2 (11.3) MB,  7.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.010, current mu = 0.003) last resort GC in old  space requested

 <--- JS stacktrace --->
==== JS stack trace =========================================

0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x36dbe9d841bd]
1: StubFrame [pc: 0x36dbea085ad7]
Security context: 0xb670dc1e6c9 <JSObject>
2: emitWarning(aka emitWarning) [0x2f6470520629]   [internal/process/promises.js:50] [bytecode=0x39e2a436f581 offset=22](this=0x2f9cf48822e1 <undefined>,uid=1,reason=0x2f9cf48ba979 <TypeError map  = 0x11c2cc49951>)
3: emitPromiseRejectionWarnings(aka emitPromiseRejectionWarnings)  [0x2f647051fe31] [internal/process/pr...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0x89c2f0 node::Abort() [npm]
2: 0x89c33c  [npm]
3: 0xa8f05e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char  const*, bool) [npm]
4: 0xa8f278  v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm]
5: 0xe7cad2  [npm]
6: 0xe8bd46 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetry(int,  v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm]
7: 0xe543fb v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex, int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [npm]
8: 0xe64b09  v8::internal::Factory::SetNumberStringCache(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [npm]
9: 0xe64ba9 v8::internal::Factory::NumberToString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool) [npm]
10: 0xf6ed72  [npm]
11: 0xf6f7e7 v8::internal::JSStackFrame::ToString() [npm]
12: 0xf71f68 v8::internal::ErrorUtils::FormatStackTrace(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [npm]
13: 0xa88587 v8::internal::Accessors::ErrorStackGetter(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [npm]
14: 0xf7587d v8::internal::PropertyCallbackArguments::BasicCallNamedGetterCallback(void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [npm]
15: 0xfa9231 v8::internal::Object::GetPropertyWithAccessor(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [npm]
16: 0xfa5430 v8::internal::Object::GetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [npm]
17: 0xeedd50 v8::internal::LoadIC::Load(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>) [npm]
18: 0xef0fb7 v8::internal::Runtime_LoadIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm]
19: 0x36dbe9d841bd
Aborted
```

when i check version of both it is working

```
$ npm -v
6.1.0

$ node -v
v10.6.0
```

Please help me i am facing problem since 2 days. Before that it was working

Comment: Can you post the whole error stack?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got only Aborted message

Comment: @eharajhusain did you try `sudo` or something?)

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance Yes i have tried.

Comment: are you sure you have a valid `package.json` in this dir? does `npm install` works without `--save`?

Comment: Yes every thing is perfect only i got error not enough memory

Comment: do you solve the problem?? I am also facing same error as you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether your nodejs and npm are installed in your system globally.If not use the below link to install it if your os is ubuntu.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks Ajay. Yes both nodejs and npm are installed i also check version of both and working fine but other command not working with npm like install, update, init etc.